# Are this maps a conformal?

Tags: complex-analysis

Are this maps (As a maps of the extended complex plane) a conformal?

1) $w = \operatorname{Ln} z,\  \lim_{t \to0}{w(1 + it)} = 2\pi i,\ D = \{0 < y < 1, x > 0\}$

2) $w = z^3,\  D = \{\frac{x^2}{2} + y^2 < 1,\  \frac{2x^2}{3} + 2y^2 > 1\}$

My solutions:

Start with the first map.
Highlight the unique branch of the logarithm:

$\lim \limits _{t \to 0} (\ln|1 + ti| + i(\operatorname{\arg} (1 + ti) + 2\pi k)) = 2\pi i k =2 \pi i$

Hence it follows that $k = 1$. Then in domain $\mathbb{C}$ without $(\infty, 0]$ we can define unique branch:

$\omega = \ln|z| + i(\operatorname{\arg} z + 2\pi)$

Let's calculate the derivative of this function. To imagine function in the form of $v(x,y) + i u(x,y)$, so

$\omega = \ln\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + i(\arctan{\frac{y}{x}} + 2\pi)$

And $\omega\ ' = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} - \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{x-y}{x^2 + y^2}$

This shows that the derivative $\omega\ '(z) = 0$ in a line $x = y$ which which overlaps the area $D$. Then this map is't conformal.

Is it correct solution?

About the second example. I think that function $w = z^3$ is one sheet in any sector with an angle of $2 \pi/3$. But we cann't put the domain $D$ in this sector. Then this map is't conformal. Is it true?